# MYSQL SYNTAX - GROUP BY WITH A CONDITION

Tags: mysql

Here is my current query that works fine but I need it to only return quantity_to_spawn > 0 when I added a where clause it was giving me an invalid group by message.

Id by glad to give more information if needed but I'm not sure its necessary at this point.
Its for a game I'm writing.

```
SELECT spawns.*, (quantity - COUNT(game_moblist.spawn_id)) AS quantity_to_spawn,mobs.*     
FROM spawns LEFT JOIN mobs USING (mob_id) LEFT JOIN game_moblist USING (spawn_id) GROUP BY 
spawn_id ORDER BY quantity_to_spawn DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a `having` instead of a `where`

```
  SELECT spawns.*, (quantity - COUNT(game_moblist.spawn_id)) AS quantity_to_spawn,
  mobs.*     
  FROM spawns 
  LEFT JOIN mobs USING (mob_id) 
  LEFT JOIN game_moblist USING (spawn_id) 
  GROUP BY spawn_id 
  having quantity_to_spawn > 0
  ORDER BY quantity_to_spawn DESC
```